# Session not created in Express

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js, passport-local

Here is the project [dev branch]: https://github.com/asid-team/library_system

I'm working on a Library App. It's server-side rendered, I'm using Express and Passport for auth and MongoDB.

The thing is, I wanted two User roles (1 for regular users, and the 1 for Librarians, the people who work in the Library). So, I came up with something shown on the links https://github.com/asid-team/library_system/tree/dev/config/routes

It works perfectly for users. Passport does all the job, and makes `req.user` after the successful login. But, the Librarian part doesn't seem to work properly: it doesn't save the Librarian session.

Can you maybe spot a mistake in my approach / code?

EDIT:
When I console.log the `req` for sessions I get:

```
sessions:
  { UaRq2ZBvDAkeckjWJU38wfdlalPmKKwb: '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{}}',
    zl24_yTpebRC6rP4I9pcNwCVKNwXa2zH: '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":"5a620ae6091a07cf8dc82fc9"}}',
    '359N-18VDvgNIDzVj-BQ_t_vdQ8Iav7H': '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":"5a61f14bb4bd20c692aa87e8"}}' },
```

These two users, `5a620ae6091a07cf8dc82fc9` and `5a61f14bb4bd20c692aa87e8`are Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` twice. The passport object is the same in both your User and Librarian route, so one is effectively ignored.

There are likely many different ways to address this problem, some more hacky than others, but [this Passportjs Github issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/50) has some discussion.

Ultimately, you'll need one set of serialize and deserialize functions to handle both User and Librarians.

Comment: True. I've done something as described by you. I've moved both of the serialise and deserialise methods in one route file and transferred them to the other one. Then I made a simple if statement to check which is which, and serialised and deserialised them in only *one* method for each of them.